# How to load txt file in haxe in js project?

Tags: haxe, flashdevelop

I've started a haxe js project in FlashDevelop, I need to load a local file, is this possible? how to to so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is use "resources". You add a path and an identifier to your `hxml`:

```
-resource hello_message.txt@welcome
```

And you use it in your code like this:

```
var welcome = haxe.Resource.getString("welcome");
```

Note that the operation is performed at compile time so there is no runtime overhead. It is essentially equivalent to embed the file content in a quoted string.

The complex answer is to use a macro. With them you can load, parse, process and do all the manipulation you might need. Pretty commonly, you can see macros to load a config file (say JSON or YAML) and use it as part of your application (again at compile time and not at runtime).

Answer (score 0):

You could grab files with an XMLHttpRequest as long as you keep them somewhere public (if you're putting it online) and accessible to the script.

Here's a quick example of grabbing a text file from the location assets/test.txt

This is the sort of thing I usually do in the JS games I make, I find it a bit more flexible than just embedding them with -resource.

If it's not exactly what you're looking for then Franco's answer should see you through.

```
package ;

import js.html.XMLHttpRequest;
import js.html.Event;

class Start {
    static function main() {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

        // using the GET method, get the file at this location, asynchronously 
        request.open("GET", "assets/test.txt", true);

        // when loaded, get the response and trace it out
        request.onload = function(e:Event){
            trace(request.response);
        };

        // if there's an error, handle it
        request.onerror = function(e:Event) {
            trace("error :(");
        };

        // send the actual request to the server
        request.send();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also use the standard haxe.Http class to load stuff. This will make it work in other platforms too.